# Wake on LAN batch script, reading MAC addresses from text file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to do wake on LAN with mc-wol.exe via batch script.
I have list of MAC addresses in mac.txt file. the script works via command line, **but not when I double click or use task scheduler**:

```
for /f %a in (mac.txt) do mc-wol.exe %a
```

Comment: did you check the paths?

Comment: in a batch file use `%%a` rather than `%a`

Comment: Thanks. worked with %%a.

Answer (score 0):

To use a `for` command in a batch script, you need to double the `%` sign of the `for` variable:

```
for /f %%a in (mac.txt) do mc-wol.exe %%a
```

This is also clearly indicated in the help documentation -- type `for /?`.